# How to use SQLite in Windows (Phone) 8.1's BackgroundTask

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1

#### Setup

I followed **[Universal App with SQLite example](http://blog.tpcware.com/2014/04/universal-app-with-sqlite-part-1/)**  to add `SQLite` to my project; then to add the `BackgroundTask` I followed **[Quickstart: Create and register a background task example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh977055.aspx)**.

#### Problem

1. The SQLite targets either `Windows Phone 8.1` or `Windows 8.1`
2. The `BackgroundTask` targets only `Windows` (being a `Windows Runtime Component`)

This is where it becomes tricky.

You cannot reference a project with the `BakgroundTask` that isn't *portable*, thus I cannot add [SQLite for Windows Runtime (Windows 8.1)](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1d04f82f-2fe9-4727-a2f9-a2db127ddc9a) or [SQLite for Windows Phone 8.1](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5d97faf6-39e3-4048-a0bc-adde2af75d1b) to the `BackgroundTask` project.

#### Question

Is there anyway to use `SQLite` in the `BackgroundTask` of Windows (Phone) 8.1 project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes the answer is easier than expected.

#### Steps

1. Set the Background Task's Library Target to only target Windows (Phone) 8.1
2. Create a `Class Library` that targets only Windows (Phone) 8.1
3. Add SQLite for Windows (Phone) 8.1 to the `Class Library`
4. Reference the `Class Library` with the Background Task

That's it!

Do most of the work in the `Class Library` and only make calls from the Background task, this makes the BGT look cleaner. The nice thing about using a `Class Library` is that you can use generics.

You will have 2 Background Tasks for your universal app

- Windows 8.1 Background Task
- Windows Phone 8.1 Background Task